# Can we get latitude and longitude without internet and only GPS?

Tags: android, gps, location, offline

Can we capture latitude and longitude from an android app offline, i.e., without an internet connection using only GPS?

If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Use the GPS_PROVIDER, and use LocationManager, not the Play Services location api